# Can't see debug print statements using Google App Engine with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to both Google App Engine and Python.  When things go wrong I'd like to see variable values and such, but print statements don't seem to be output anywhere.  I would have expected them to appear in the same window where I started dev_appserver, but the only time I can see them is if a server error is imminent, then they appear in the output as I'd expect, right before the server error.  Otherwise I don't see them.

I'm sure I'm missing something very fundamental... it seems everyone else can see their print statements just fine.  I have tried using the logger functionality, but best I can tell it is intended for deployed apps.  At any rate I can't see any output from those either.  A simple example:

```
class PageHandler(BaseHandler):
def get(self): 
    // the page renders just fine, but no print statement to be found
    print "rendering the page!"        
    self.render("page.html")
```

Am I just looking in the wrong spot for the print output?  Do I need to be doing something to redirect output before printing?  Very confused why the print statements work only when an error is about to occur.

Comment: You should be using logging, and not print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` outputs to standard output (`sys.stdout`) whose destination on a web app is always iffy.  Rather, use the `logging` module...:

```
import logging
...
logging.info('rendering the page')
```

and you'll be able to see all messages in the logs.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use logging.debug but hadn't set log_level to debug when running dev_appserver.  Looks like info is better for basic debugging so my messages are easier to find in the logs.